# Difference between void* varname and Object varname in cpp

Tags: c++, object

I have come from a C background and what i understand is that there is no difference between a void pointer and struct pointer because they are literally same sized addresses to somewhere.

Am I wrong?

If not, is this thing same in cpp as well? what's the difference between object varname and object* varname and void* varname?

Comment: One is a pointer the other one is not?

Comment: i edited the question. can you please read it again?

Comment: There is a difference between a `void*` and a `struct something*` in C - one of them has a concrete type

Comment: how are they treated differently?

Comment: `void*` has **no** type (safety) - you need to first cast it to a concrete type (and if the pointed to object is not of the given type then you will invoke *undefined behavior* when dereferencing that pointer)

Comment: and can you tell me how the difference between object varname and object* varname

Answer (score 0):

In both C and C++ the following code is valid:

```
Object obj;
Object *objp = &obj;
void *voidp = objp;
```

That is, there is an **implicit conversion** from a pointer-to-object-type to a pointer-to-void.

In C, the following code is also legal:

```
Object *objp1 = voidp;
```

That is, there is also an implicit conversion going the other way.

In C++ that conversion is not legal; you must use a cast:

```
Object *objp1 = voidp;                       // Error: invalid conversion
Object *objp1 = static_cast<Object*>(voidp); // Ok: cast says to do it
```

In both languages, if you convert a void pointer into a pointer to some other type and the pointer did not, in fact, point to an object of that type, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: You need reinterpret_cast to convert pointers of unrelated types.

Comment: @AndreiAndrey — that’s true, but not an issue here. You can use `static_cast` to convert a `void*` to an object pointer.